# InvalidOperationException on File return

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

am running into some weird issue when i try to return a file to be downloaded, 
so this is my code

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path1, Path2, filename);
return File(filePath, "audio/mp3", "myfile.mp3");
```

but the problem it return this error

**InvalidOperationException: No file provider has been configured to process the supplied file.**

am not sure what i have missed, any help ?

Comment: Is this a whole code of your download method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so the way to return a File method , is as @SeM suggest but by removing the file name from file path.

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path1, Path2);

IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(filePath);
IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(filename);
var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();

return File(readStream, "audio/mpeg", fileName);
```

Answer (score 26):

You can simply change your code from:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path1, Path2, filename);
return File(filePath, "audio/mp3", "myfile.mp3");
```

to this:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path1, Path2, filename);
return PhysicalFile(filePath, "audio/mp3", "myfile.mp3");
```

Then problem solved!

You can also put your files under `wwwroot` folder (your **web root** folder). Then you can use **relative path** to the **web root** folder and put `filePath` into first argument of the [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-3.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_String_System_String_) method. Then you can access the file without problem. This will be much safer than using `PhysicalFile` method.

Answer (score 3):

you first need to create file provider registration.

```
services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(  
       new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

then you can use it like this

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IFileProvider _fileProvider;

    public IndexModel(IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {
        _fileProvider = fileProvider;
    }

    public IFileInfo FileInfo { get; private set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        IFileInfo = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo("filename.ext");
    }
}
```

in your case your function body would be like

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path1, Path2, filename);
IFileInfo = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo(filepath);
var fs = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
return File(fs, "audio/mp3", "myfile.mp3");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, but am a bit confused,,, where is the "return File()" and what the DirectoryContents  have to do with return File method ?

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net core you need to [PhysicalFileProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2#physicalfileprovider) to access physical file system:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path1, Path2, filename);

IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(filePath);
IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(filename);
var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();

return File(readStream, "audio/mpeg", fileName);
```

Also as far as I know, mime type of `.mp3` file is `audio/mpeg`.

Comment: not sure why , but it return to me an error,
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Comment: in the : 
IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(filePath);

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Comment: ArgumentException: The directory name 'C:\folder\file.mp3\' does not exist.
Parameter name: path
System.IO.FileSystemWatcher..ctor(string path, string filter)

Comment: What's your `filename` value? "file.mp3\" ?

Comment: Correct your directory names and filename and everything should work correctly.

Comment: file name cannot contain `\\`` it should be only `file.mp3`.

Comment: that is awkward, in the debugger the filePath is correct and contain no back slash